# Setting stack size for thread run with QtConcurrent

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread, qtconcurrent

How to set stack size for thread run with `QtConcurrent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not actually possible (there is a change request for this https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-2568). You have to use `QThread` instead, and call `setStackSize()` before starting your thread.